# Why other languages character doesn't show in browser title bar?

Tags: xhtml, unicode, browser

Why other languages character doesn't show in browser title bar?

for example see this http://chhotikashi.com/

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me (Firefox on Windows 7): बीकानेर, राजस्थान से अंतर्जाल पर प्रकाशित एक हिन्दी लोकप्रिय समाचार पत्र  but doesn't work on any browser in Windows XP SP3 german.

As I said in the comments, this is probably down to the installed font(s) not supporting the character set. Installing the language in Windows would probably help. Here is more info: [**Unicode and Multilingual Support in HTML, Fonts, Web Browsers and Other Applications**](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/)

Comment: if this is a problem then why it's working fine on your system. I'm on Windows XP and looking in Firefox 3.6. I've faced this situation on many sites not only on this

Comment: Hmmm. It could be that Windows 7's system font has the characters (what are they called by the way)? And Windows XP's doesn't. Have you tried it with a localized version of Windows XP or an english one?

Comment: @jitendra both sites work fine with Firefox and IE on Windows 7, but on a Windows XP (SP3, german) I don't get the non-western characters. But as a reconciliation, I get a massive background tune :)

Comment: @jitendra I'm pretty sure it's the system font that lacks the characters. I think this can be sorted by installing the actual language in the "languages" part of the windows control panel. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Pekka - if font is not in my PC then why whole site is showing fine in my browser only browser title showing garbage characters. I'm only talking about browser's title bar not in website. in website content everything is fine. I'm using firefox 3.6

Comment: @Jitendra the font you are using to display the window titles is different from what Firefox uses to render the document with. You can change the font in Windows's settings. You could try downloading a "full" unicode font, or installing the language on your machine. Both should help the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine in Firefox on Vista for me. The computer you're on likely has an older version of whatever font Firefox uses in the title bar. That font doesn't have the glyphs for your language.

Answer (score 0):

Its depend on Your PC Regional Setting configuration, So check if you installed considering language or not.